# Why does text 'pdf 2' display when using includegraphics in Sweave

Tags: r, pdf, latex, x11, sweave

If a pdf document is created using the following Sweave (R/LaTeX) code, then in the top left of the figure there will be text `pdf 2`; note this is not embedded in the `png` but is actually text you can highlight.

In the `.Rnw`:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
<<fig=FALSE,echo=FALSE>>=
    png("test0.png",width=4,height=4,units='in',res=1200)
    plot(1)
    dev.off()
@
    \includegraphics{test0.png}
    \caption{Demonstration}
\end{figure}
```

Then in `R`:

> Sweave("report.Rnw") ; texi2pdf("report.tex")

How do I fix this?

I am using a very recent version of `R` on Ubuntu.

Comment: That is probably due to something else in your `report.Rnw` file (in particular, the problem is not reproducible). It may disappear if you add `results=hide`.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd Correct. Submit answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
<<fig=FALSE,echo=FALSE>>=
    png("test0.png",width=4,height=4,units='in',res=1200)
    plot(1)
    dev.off()
@
    \includegraphics{test0.png}
    \caption{Demonstration}
\end{figure}
```

there is a `null device 1` message that appears before the plot
It is the output of the R commands that generate the plot.
You can suppress it by adding `results=hide`.

```
<<fig=FALSE,echo=FALSE,results=hide>>=
```

Your message is slightly different because `dev.off()` returns the name of the current device:
there was none in my case (it was a fresh session), 
and a previously opened (but not closed) PDF file in your case.